# How can I get the binary version of a Github Release Asset using Powershell?

Tags: powershell-3.0, github-api

I am following the docs from [GitHub Releases](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release-asset), but all I ever get returned is the asset contents.

Here is my powershell script:

```
$gitHubRepository = "<repo>"
$gitHubUsername = "<username>"
$gitHubApiKey = "<apikey>"

# Locate Latest GitHub Release
$releaseParams = @{
    Uri = "https://api.github.com/repos/$gitHubUsername/$gitHubRepository/releases";
    Method = 'GET';
    Headers = @{
        Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String(
            [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($gitHubApiKey + ":x-oauth-basic")
        );
    }
    ContentType = 'application/json';
    Body = (ConvertTo-Json $releaseData -Compress)
}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod @releaseParams

$tag = $result.tag_name[0]
Write-Host "Release $tag Found."

$asset = $result.assets[0].url
$ZipFile = $result.assets[0].name
$asset

$releaseAssetParams = @{
    Uri = $asset;
    Method = 'GET';
    Headers = @{
        Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($gitHubApiKey + ":x-oauth-basic"));
    }
    ContentType = 'application/octet-stream';
}

Invoke-RestMethod @releaseAssetParams -OutFile $ZipFile
```

Executing this script (with the variables set correctly), outputs the asset contents, not the binary (zip) file as expected.

Is the content-type not getting recognized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `application/octet-stream` in an `Accept` request header, not a `Content-Type` request header, because you want to tell the server what you want to accept, not what you're sending.

So, you need to send a header like this:

```
Accept: application/octet-stream
```

and not

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

The response from the API will be a redirect to the URL which has the actual asset, so you'll need to make another request (this is expected behavior). If you run into problems, [let us know](https://github.com/contact).

Comment: Works great with Powershell 4.0 after they fixed the bug not allowing Accept Headers to be set.

Comment: @SamTyson Then, don't forget to accept the answer. `:-)`